# why the http post request doesn't have the header gzip, but http response does?

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

why doesn't the http request use `content-encoding: gzip` in its post body? Is this on purpose? Thanks.

Below is a demo request header

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 353
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Cookie: xxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: Fetch
```

and here is a response header:

```
cache-control: private, private
Cache-Control: private
Connection: keep-alive
content-encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 08:22:02 GMT
Server: Tengine
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients *can* encode their request bodies just as servers can:

> [RFC 7231             HTTP/1.1 Semantics and Content 3.1.2.2.  Content-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.2)

> [...]

> An origin server MAY respond with a status code of 415 (Unsupported
> Media Type) if a representation in the request message has a content
> coding that is not acceptable.

And that excerpt immediately indicates the problem: discoverability. The client doesn't know whether the server will accept the gzipped request body, so to be safe, web browsers in general don't zip their request bodies.

You can do that manually if you control a part of the stack, for example if you execute requests from JavaScript, as explained in this blog: [Put Your HTTP Requests on a Diet](https://medium.com/axiomzenteam/put-your-http-requests-on-a-diet-3e1e52333014).

There is a proposal, by Julian Reschke (who may coincidentally answer this question as well as they're pretty active in the [http](/questions/tagged/http) tag on Stack Overflow) which is worth a read:

[RFC 7694   Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Client-Initiated Content-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7694):

> In HTTP, content codings allow for payload encodings such as for
> compression or integrity checks.  In particular, the "gzip" content
> coding is widely used for payload data sent in response messages.

> Content codings can be used in request messages as well; however,
> discoverability is not on par with response messages.  This document
> extends the HTTP "Accept-Encoding" header field for use in responses,
> to indicate the content codings that are supported in requests.